# Why I have to give a negative two offset for seekg for end of file

Tags: c++, iostream

So I was reading about file handling and wanted to read a text file from the end. So I decided to seek the get pointer to the last character using,

`seekg(-2,ios::end);`

My complete code is:

```
fin.open("source.txt");
fin.seekg(-2,ios::end);

fin>>ch;
if(fin.fail())
    cout<<"uh oh!";
else
    cout<<ch;
```

My question is that why I have to make the offset -2 and not -1 as I assume that the `ios::end` places the get pointer to one position after the last valid character of the file.

Any help?
Thanks.

Comment: Open the file in binary mode instead of text mode and rerun your test.

Comment: You are right. That is a convention in c/c++: ranges are usually [inclusive, exclusive)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie , Even in the binary mode, the stream fails when I give an offset of -1. Works with -2.

Comment: @askshay when you say it doesn't work, do you mean it displays "uh oh !" ?  Do you set any locale in your code ?

Comment: @Christophe, Yes, it displays "uh oh!" (The stream failed).

Comment: On which OS are you working ? Do you set any locale in your code ?  Can you confirm it's a narrow stream ?

Comment: @Christophe, I am on Visual Studio 2012 (Windows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of your error is that you use `>>` and certainly have as last character a `'\n'` or a space.

Seeking with -1 positions you on the '\n',  but its ignored by the extractor `>>` (it [skips all whitespaces](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/skipws/) and '\n').  If you position one character before, with -2, you certainly get on the last non space character and it works.

To really see what's going on at the end of the file:

```
in.open("source.txt");
fin.seekg(-1,ios::end);  // -1 is really the last char of the file 

ch = fin.get();  // read one character without ignoring anything
if(fin.fail())
    cout<<"uh oh!";
else
    cout<<(int)ch <<"="<<ch<<endl;  // display char code (if not printable) and char
```